# ¿Cómo se pasa el operador PHP << a LUA?

Tags: php, lua, operador

Buenas. Verán, tengo un código en PHP y necesito pasarlo a LUA.

Este es el código original en PHP:

```
function udb_hash($buf) { 
$length=strlen($buf); 
$s1 = 1; 
$s2 = 0; 
for($n=0; $n<$length; $n++) 
{ 
   $s1 = ($s1 + ord($buf[$n])) % 65521; 
   $s2 = ($s2 + $s1) % 65521; 
} 
return ($s2 << 16) + $s1; }
```

Estoy consiguiendo todo, pero cuando llego a la última línea no sé como pasarlo a LUA. Aquí les dejo el código que llevo pasado a LUA:

```
function udb_hash (clave)
length = string.len(clave)
s1 = 1 
s2 = 0
for i = 0, (length-1) do
   s1 = (s1 + string.byte(tostring(clave), i)) % 65521
   s2 = (s2 + s1) % 65521
end
return (s2 << 16) + s1 end // Aquí es donde viene el problema.
```

¿Voy bien con la conversión? ¿Cómo haría para transofrmar ese << de PHP a LUA?

Saludos y gracias por gastar el tiempo en leerme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por la ayuda. El problema es que eso me funciona a partir de LUA 5.3+ y mi versión es más antigua. Al final conseguí solucionarlo así:

```
function lshift(x, by)
    return x * 2 ^ by
end

function udb_hash (clave)
    length = string.len(clave)
    s1 = 1 
    s2 = 0
    for i = 1, length do
        aSumar = tonumber(string.byte(tostring(clave), tonumber(i)))
        s1 = tonumber(s1 + aSumar) % 65521
        s2 = (s2 + s1) % 65521
    end
    return (lshift(s2,16)) + s1
end
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Se usa la función:

```
bit.blshift(n, bits);
```

[Puedes encontrar la documentación de los operadores de bits para LUA aquí.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators)

Saludos.